# Pass Laravel data to Vue component using vue router

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have a laravel collection that should pass json data to a vue component

```
 $problems = $maintenance->getMaintenanceTypes();

 return new MaintenanceTypesCollection($problems);
```

I'm then creating a radio button using that json collection

```
<div v-for="m_type in maintenance_types" :key="m_type.id">
              <input type="radio" v-model="form.m_type" :value="m_type.id" :id="m_type.id">
              <label :for="m_type.id">{{ m_type.problem }}</label>
  </div>
```

and the data is being passed well when I'm using Laravel web routing but when I switch to Vue router the data is not being passed at all.

For reference here is my routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/maintenance/types', 'Maintenance\MaintenanceTypesController@index');
```

Here is my Vuex store

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { data } from 'jquery'

export default {

namespaced: true,

state:{
    maintenance_types: []
},

getters:{

    maintenance_types (state) {
        return state.maintenance_types
    }

},

mutations:{
    PUSH_M_TYPE (state, data) {
        state.maintenance_types.push(...data)
    }
},

actions:{
    async getMaintenanceTypes ({ commit }) {
            let response = await axios.get('/maintenance/types')

            commit('PUSH_M_TYPE', response.data.data)
    }

}

}
```

And here is my Vue component script logic

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            form: {
                description: '',
                m_type: ''
            }
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            maintenance_types: 'maintenance/maintenance_types'
        })
    },

    methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            getMaintenanceTypes: 'maintenance/getMaintenanceTypes'
        }),

       async submit () {
           await axios.post('/api/maintenance/store', this.form)
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        this.getMaintenanceTypes()
    }

}
```

When I'm using this Vue routing it is not working

```
import AppMaintenanceForm from './components/maintenance/AppMaintenanceForm.vue'
export const routes = [
 {
        path: '/maintenance/form',
        component: AppMaintenanceForm,
        name: 'MaintenanceForm'

    },
]
```

but when I switch to Laravel's routes/web.php it is working. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: `/maintenance/types` it return json data or view .?

Comment: /maintenance/types returns purely json data. That data should  then be retrieved in the Vuex store and using getters is passed on to the Vue Component